# How to sum rows of different table and append in a new table with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have six html tables each with there own theme. Each table has two rows. Each row has to have a total sum. The sum of each table has to be placed in a another table (the table_tot). The code I discoverd does nearly the trick, but it sums all the row of all the tables at the end. In the code you can see that the second row in the table_tot is the sum of alle the rows of the two tables. I've tried to gave the td another class name, but that was not the solution. I hope someone has. My knowledge of javascript or jquery is very little.

```js
var totals = [0, 0];
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $dataRows = $(".table_1 tr:not('.titlerow')");
  $dataRows.each(function() {
    $(this).find('.count').each(function(i) {
      totals[i] += parseInt($(this).html());
    });

    $(".table_tot td.totalCol_1").each(function(i) {
      $(this).html(+totals[i]);
    });
  });

  var $dataRows = $(".table_2 tr:not('.titlerow')");
  $dataRows.each(function() {
    $(this).find('.count').each(function(i) {
      totals[i] += parseInt($(this).html());
    });

    $(".table_tot td.totalCol_2").each(function(i) {
      $(this).html(+totals[i]);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table_1">
  <tr class="titlerow">
    <th>Thema</th>
    <th>Moment 1</th>
    <th>Moment 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Theme 1</td>
      <td class="count">4</td>
      <td class="count">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Theme 2</td>
      <td class="count">5</td>
      <td class="count">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Theme 3</td>
      <td class="count">8</td>
      <td class="count">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Theme 4</td>
      <td class="count">4</td>
      <td class="count">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Theme 5</td>
      <td class="count">4</td>
      <td class="count">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Theme 6</td>
      <td class="count">6</td>
      <td class="count">8</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<table class="table_2">
  <tr class="titlerow">
    <th>Theme</th>
    <th>Moment 1</th>
    <th>Moment 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Theme 1</td>
      <td class="count">4</td>
      <td class="count">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Theme 2</td>
      <td class="count">5</td>
      <td class="count">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Theme 3</td>
      <td class="count">8</td>
      <td class="count">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Theme 4</td>
      <td class="count">4</td>
      <td class="count">9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Theme 5</td>
      <td class="count">4</td>
      <td class="count">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Theme 6</td>
      <td class="count">6</td>
      <td class="count">8</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>


<table class="table_tot">
  <tr>
    <th>Thema</th>
    <th>Moment 1</th>
    <th>Moment 2</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Theme 1</td>
    <td class="totalCol_1"></td>
    <td class="totalCol_1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Theme 2</td>
    <td class="totalCol_2"></td>
    <td class="totalCol_2"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: **Each table has two rows.** Your tables each have 6 rows. Did you mean two columns?

Comment: You have two tables with 6 rows, not 6 tables with 2 rows.

Comment: Can you show what the desired result is supposed to be? Your description is very confusing, maybe because English isn't your language.

Comment: Sorry it's two columns and 6 rows. In the table with class="tabel_tot" the first row ("totalCol_1") should have the totals of the first table, the second row ("totalCol_2")of the second table and this up to the sixth table which comes in the sixth row.

Comment: It's still not clear what result you're trying to get. Why does `table_tot` only have 2 themes instead of 6?

Comment: I thought two table and the total_table would be enough to show what I was looking for. Basis it's six table where the seventh is filled by the total rows of the the six tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sums of the 2nd row of `table_tot` are the sums of all table rows because `totals` isn't `[0,0]` when the sums of `table_2` are calculated, but `[31,38]`. The easiest way to solve this is to have a 2nd `totals` variable:

```js
var totals = [0, 0];
var totals2 = [0, 0];
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $dataRows = $(".table_1 tr:not('.titlerow')");
  $dataRows.each(function() {
    $(this).find('.count').each(function(i) {
      totals[i] += parseInt($(this).html());
    });

    $(".table_tot td.totalCol_1").each(function(i) {
      $(this).html(+totals[i]);
    });
  });

  var $dataRows = $(".table_2 tr:not('.titlerow')");
  $dataRows.each(function() {
    $(this).find('.count').each(function(i) {
      totals2[i] += parseInt($(this).html());
    });

    $(".table_tot td.totalCol_2").each(function(i) {
      $(this).html(+totals2[i]);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table_1">
  <tr class="titlerow">
    <th>Thema</th>
    <th>Moment 1</th>
    <th>Moment 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Theme 1</td>
      <td class="count">4</td>
      <td class="count">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Theme 2</td>
      <td class="count">5</td>
      <td class="count">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Theme 3</td>
      <td class="count">8</td>
      <td class="count">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Theme 4</td>
      <td class="count">4</td>
      <td class="count">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Theme 5</td>
      <td class="count">4</td>
      <td class="count">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Theme 6</td>
      <td class="count">6</td>
      <td class="count">8</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<table class="table_2">
  <tr class="titlerow">
    <th>Theme</th>
    <th>Moment 1</th>
    <th>Moment 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Theme 1</td>
      <td class="count">4</td>
      <td class="count">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Theme 2</td>
      <td class="count">5</td>
      <td class="count">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Theme 3</td>
      <td class="count">8</td>
      <td class="count">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Theme 4</td>
      <td class="count">4</td>
      <td class="count">9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Theme 5</td>
      <td class="count">4</td>
      <td class="count">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Theme 6</td>
      <td class="count">6</td>
      <td class="count">8</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>


<table class="table_tot">
  <tr>
    <th>Thema</th>
    <th>Moment 1</th>
    <th>Moment 2</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Theme 1</td>
    <td class="totalCol_1"></td>
    <td class="totalCol_1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Theme 2</td>
    <td class="totalCol_2"></td>
    <td class="totalCol_2"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks matthias_h, that's the answer I was looking for

Comment: @lycaon Glad that I was able to help :) If this answered your question, please check the checkmark next to the answer so your question is resolved as answered/solved.